# child_process exec can not response to client broswer

Tags: node.js

I am trying to execute an command via `child_process` module and reponse the result to client browser as below, `console.log(stdout)` work find, but the `response.write()` doesen't work.

```
function start(response) {
    dir_list(function(stdout) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        console.log(stdout);
        response.end();
});     

function dir_list(callback) {
     var exec = require('child_process').exec
     child = exec('ls -la', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
         callback(stdout);
     });
}
```

Above code is refractored by me which I refer to
[Node.js: Object value as stdout of child_process.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270857/node-js-object-value-as-stdout-of-child-process-exec), but, unluckly it doesn't work for me.

BTW, my originally code is:

```
  function start(response) {
      console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
      var exec = require('child_process').exec;
      exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write(stdout);
      console.log(stdout);
      response.end();
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is the response received on the client side? Any error messages?

Comment: @supertopi it doesn't work means when I get nothing in my browser. but it's wired that "console.log(stdout);" work fine, in other word, I can get the log information in the console.

Comment: @Eloff the original code work did not work neither.

Comment: @supertopi I have solved the issue, whatever, thanks for your take care the question. Just caused by my careless!

Comment: @Eloff thanks for your take care the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a close `}` at the end of the `start` function.

```
function start(response) {
    dir_list(function(stdout) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        console.log(stdout);
        response.end();
    });
}

function dir_list(callback) {
     var exec = require('child_process').exec
     child = exec('ls -la', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
         callback(stdout);
     });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your information, yes, '}' is lost by me when I copy my code to Stackoverflow. I have found the root cause is that I call response.end() before I call start() method as below. 
    

    router.route(handle, pathName, response);
    response.end();

the solutin is just remove the "reponse.end()"

Comment: @Weibo When you can post that as an answer.

Comment: I was trying to get something like this working for a while but I came across this... thank you ....thank you ...thank you . you are a super ★